# How do I make a fading status bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design, statusbar

What I want to achieve is that the status bar should fade along with the action bar on scroll the page.

Comment: Fade from what and to what? What code have you written so far - I assume you have the desired effect from your Action Bar?

Comment: Check the link if you trying to say this https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02